# How could I implement POS Tagger using HMM with Viterbi Algorithm in Python(IPython)?

Tags: python

I was trying to implement a **POS tagge**r for **resource-scarce language**. For the implementation, I've my own manually **tagged corpus** in a quite small amount. Having this corpus, I've been dealing with the development of PoS Tagger in supervised mode on the **Jupyter** environment. Over the course of the attempt, I have challenged by applying the performance optimization algorithms(**Viterbi**) as I was naive to python merely but not to others. Thus I need good provisions from this community if one who could provide me with the simplest way of applying this algorithm along with **HMM**. I am just worried!